No me funciona Android Studio
soy nuevo aprendiendo Android Studio. Instale el IDE y cada vez que creo un proyecto nuevo me da error. Probé cambiando la versión de gradle y no funciono. Busque en varios lados y no encontré la forma de resolverlo. Quiero solucionarlo para poder aprender pero  me siento estancado y no tengo conocidos que programe Android para que me ayude. Dejo los errores que me figuran:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.4.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Segundo error:
Unsupported Java. 
Your build is currently configured to use Java 22.0.1 and Gradle 8.6.

En
build.gradle.kts
tengo lo siguiente que se puso por defecto una vez creada la app:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
}

Gracias por ayudarme con mi primera duda

Hola. ¿Si vas al menú File y luego Project Structure qué ves al seleccionar la ventana de Project?. Ahí deberías ver tu versión del plugin de Gradle así como la versión de Gradle en sí misma.

En Android Gradle Plugin Version me dice 8.0.0 y en gradle version 8.6, esta bien?

¿En vez de la captura de pantalla podrías agregar el mensaje de error completo, así como el contenido del archivo gradle?

me da este error :
Build file 'C:\Users\Julian Garibotto\MyApplications2\build.gradle.kts' line: 2
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.4.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
y este otro :
Unsupported Java.
Your build is currently configured to use Java 22.0.1 and Gradle 8.6.
Possible solution:

Open Gradle wrapper settings, change distributionUrl property to use compatible Gradle version and reload the project


y el contenido del archivo gradle :
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
}

Eso va en la pregunta, no en comentarios. Pulsa [edit] para agregar toda información relevante y el contenido de tu archivo gradle.

Edité tu pregunta para corregir ortografía, pero con la gramática está complicado. Hay signos de puntuación. Por ejemplo, no es lo mismo "pero tampoco busqué en varios lados", que quiere decir que no buscaste mucho a: "pero tampoco. Busqué en varios lados", que significa una cosa muy distinta. Como no sé lo que quieres decir, no agregué puntuación, pero sería bueno que lo hagas tú mismo. Un saludo.

Muchas gracias a los dos, ya modifique todo y trate de ponerlo lo más correcto posible. Espero quede bien expresada mi duda y perdón por la mala redacción y falta de información.
